# Strange behavior of psline with tbar ends

Tags: pstricks

I use tbars to show errors in my bar graphs. However, some of the errors are very small. With those small errors, the tbars are shown in a strange way. They start at the first coordinate and grow over the second coordinate, depending on the linewidth and the length of the line. Is it possible to prevent the line ends from growing over the limits of the line?
See following MWE:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot,pst-bar,pst-fill,multido}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(3,3)%
\psaxes(0,0)(2,2)
\psset{tbarsize = 4pt}

% Show mentioned behavior with different linewidths and exchanging the start of the line. 
\multido{\dX = 0.1pt + 0.2pt, \nX=0.1+0.2}{5}{\psline[linewidth=\dX]{|-|}(\nX,0.835)(\nX,0.825)
\multido{\dX = 0.1pt + 0.2pt, \nX=0.1+0.2}{5}{\psline[linewidth=\dX]{|-|}(\nX,0.525)(\nX,0.535)}

% Show mentioned behavior with different linewidths and different line lengths
\multido{\dX = 0.1pt + 0.2pt, \nX=0.1+0.2, \nY = 1.405 + 0.010}{10}{\psline[linewidth=1.2pt]{|-|}(\nX,1.4)(\nX,\nY)}
\multido{\dX = 0.1pt + 0.2pt, \nX=0.1+0.2, \nY = 1.605 + 0.010}{10}{\psline{|-|}(\nX,1.6)(\nX,\nY)}
\multido{\dX = 0.1pt + 0.2pt, \nX=0.1+0.2, \nY = 1.805 + 0.010}{10}{\psline[linewidth=0.4pt]{|-|}(\nX,1.8)(\nX,\nY)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\psline[...]{|*-|*}(...)`:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido,pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.75,-0.75)(3,3)%
\psaxes(0,0)(2,2)
\psset{tbarsize = 4pt}

% Show mentioned behavior with different linewidths and exchanging the start of the line. 
\psset{linecolor=red}
\multido{\dX = 0.1pt + 0.2pt, \nX=0.1+0.2}{5}{\psline[linewidth=\dX]{|*-|*}(\nX,0.835)(\nX,0.825)}
\multido{\dX = 0.1pt + 0.2pt, \nX=0.1+0.2}{5}{\psline[linewidth=\dX]{|*-|*}(\nX,0.525)(\nX,0.535)}

\psset{linecolor=blue}
% Show mentioned behavior with different linewidths and different line lengths
\multido{\dX = 0.1pt + 0.2pt, \nX=0.1+0.2, \nY = 1.405 + 
0.010}{10}{\psline[linewidth=1.2pt]{|*-|*}(\nX,1.4)(\nX,\nY)}
\multido{\dX = 0.1pt + 0.2pt, \nX=0.1+0.2, \nY = 1.605 + 
0.010}{10}{\psline{|*-|*}(\nX,1.6)(\nX,\nY)}
\multido{\dX = 0.1pt + 0.2pt, \nX=0.1+0.2, \nY = 1.805 + 
0.010}{10}{\psline[linewidth=0.4pt]{|*-|*}(\nX,1.8)(\nX,\nY)}
\end{pspicture}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.75,-0.75)(3,3)%
\psaxes(0,0)(2,2)
\psset{tbarsize = 4pt}
% Show mentioned behavior with different linewidths and exchanging the start of the line. 
\multido{\dX = 0.1pt + 0.2pt, \nX=0.1+0.2}{5}{\psline[linewidth=\dX]{|-|}(\nX,0.835)(\nX,0.825)}
\multido{\dX = 0.1pt + 0.2pt, \nX=0.1+0.2}{5}{\psline[linewidth=\dX]{|-|}(\nX,0.525)(\nX,0.535)}

% Show mentioned behavior with different linewidths and different line lengths
\multido{\dX = 0.1pt + 0.2pt, \nX=0.1+0.2, \nY = 1.405 + 
0.010}{10}{\psline[linewidth=1.2pt]{|-|}(\nX,1.4)(\nX,\nY)}
\multido{\dX = 0.1pt + 0.2pt, \nX=0.1+0.2, \nY = 1.605 + 0.010}{10}{\psline{|-|}(\nX,1.6)(\nX,\nY)}
\multido{\dX = 0.1pt + 0.2pt, \nX=0.1+0.2, \nY = 1.805 + 
0.010}{10}{\psline[linewidth=0.4pt]{|-|}(\nX,1.8)(\nX,\nY)}

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]